# Map on a set is not triggered if an item is updated

Tags: gun

*gun 0.8.7, Node.js-to-Node.js, no browser.*

Nodes are successfully created and added to the `tasks` set

```
const Gun = require('gun');
const _ = require('lodash');
require( "gun/lib/path" );

const gun = new Gun({peers:['http://localhost:8080/gun', 'http://localhost:8081/gun']});

const watchers = [
  {
    id: '123',
    type: 'skeleton',
    stat: {
      num: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id: '456',
    type: 'snowmann',
    stat: {
      num: 0
    }
  },
  {
    id: '789',
    type: 'moose',
    stat: {
      num: 0
    },
  }
]; 

const tasks = gun.get('tasks'); 

_.forEach(watchers, function (watcher) {
  let task = gun.get(`watcher/${watcher.id}`).put(watcher);
  tasks.set(task);
});
```

There are results of the `.map` evaluation

```
a2task { _:
   { '#': 'watcher/123',
     '>': { id: 1506959623558, type: 1506959623558, stat: 1506959623558 } },
  id: '123',
  type: 'skeleton',
  stat: { '#': 'j8acunbf70NblJptwXWa' } }
task { _:
   { '#': 'watcher/456',
     '>':
      { id: 1506959623579.002,
        type: 1506959623579.002,
        stat: 1506959623579.002 } },
  id: '456',
  type: 'snowmann',
  stat: { '#': 'j8acunbv03sor9v0NeHs7cITj' } }
task { _:
   { '#': 'watcher/789',
     '>':
      { id: 1506959623581.002,
        type: 1506959623581.002,
        stat: 1506959623581.002 } },
  id: '789',
  type: 'moose',
  stat: { '#': 'j8acunbx03sorM0hWZdQz0IyL' } }
```

on a listener side

```
const Gun = require('gun');

const gun = new Gun({peers:['http://localhost:8080/gun']});
const tasks = gun.get('tasks');
tasks.map().val(function (task) {
  console.log('task', task);
});
```

But there are no results if one of the properties updated:

```
_.forEach(watchers, function (watcher) {
  gun.get(`watcher/${watcher.id}`).put({
    stat: {
      num: 1
    }
  });
```

Why?

Here is the code to play with https://github.com/sergibondarenko/shared-schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets no update because you're not mapping that level.  'stat' is already a property that is an object so you get no change.

```
tasks.map().map().val(function (task_stat) {
  console.log('task stat', task_stat);
});
```

Comment: @trex was this maybe related to the bug you found that I just fixed in v0.8.9? Could you try again and report back here on SO if things now work?